# How to calculate the number of digits ($D$) of a natural number ($N$) in base $10$?

Tags: number-theory

I have figured out that:

> Given $N = 10^K$, $D = K + 1$.

What is the formula for a natural number $D = {???}(N)$

How to solve this in Mathematica/WolframAlpha ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that the answer is

```
D = Floor[Log10[N]] + 1
```

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Floor[Log10[2011]]+%2B+1

Answer (score 1):

You have it (presuming that you see 000 as having 2 leading zeros and make a special case for it-the log won't work well).  Just round Z up to the next $10^k-1$, or use the ceiling function:  $\lceil log_{10}(N+1)\rceil$

With the change to the question, see the Hristo's comment below

Comment: I'm sorry, I figured out that the question in it's original form is incorrect, so I changed it. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Maybe it is Floor[Log10[N]] + 1 ?

Comment: @Hristo:  I agree

Answer (score 0):

IntegerLength[n]

gives the number of digits in the base 10 representation of the integer n.